# How to send a XML API request in cypress (SOAP API)

Tags: api, soap, request, cypress

I need to send XML requests in cypress but I don't know how to do that. Generally, I worked with cy.request with rest API's. Is it possible to send XML requests in cypress?
How can I do that? Any help would be great!! An example would be lovely!

I left an example request that I use in postman without a problem. But to automate my test I need to send that request in cypress.
(POST request)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <MT_ServiceOrderInitiaionandMgmt xmlns:prx="***"
                                    xmlns="***">
            <VKONTO>***</VKONTO> 
            <NAME>***</NAME> 
            <PORTION>***</PORTION>  
            <AKLASSE/>
            <DATUM>***</DATUM> 
            <Contact>
                <RELTYP/>
                <NAME>***</NAME>
                <TEL_NUMBER>***</TEL_NUMBER>
                <PHTYPE>***</PHTYPE>
                <SMTP_ADDR>***</SMTP_ADDR>
            </Contact>
            <LifeSupportIndicator/>
            <QMNUM>***</QMNUM> 
            <QMART>***</QMART>
            <MNCOD>***</MNCOD> 
            <QMTXT>***</QMTXT>
            <NOTST>***</NOTST>
            <ServiceAddress>
                <STREET>***</STREET>
                <CITY1>***</CITY1>
                <REGIO>***</REGIO>
                <LOCATION>***</LOCATION>
                <POST_CODE1>***</POST_CODE1>
                <HAUS_NUM2/>
            </ServiceAddress>
            <ABLEINH>***</ABLEINH>
            <CO_ASTTX>***</CO_ASTTX> 
            <STRMN/>
            <STRUR>***</STRUR> 
            <LTRMN/>
            <LTRUR>***</LTRUR> 
            <ERDAT>***</ERDAT> 
            <MZEIT>***</MZEIT> 
            <ERNAM>***</ERNAM>
            <AEDAT/>
            <AEZEIT>***</AEZEIT>
            <AENAM/>
            <PPSID>***</PPSID>
            <ExternalReference>
                <ID></ID>
                <SYSNAME>***</SYSNAME>
                <TYPE>***</TYPE>
            </ExternalReference>
            <REFNUM/>
            <PRIOK/> 
            <LONT_TXT>***</LONT_TXT> 
            <PREMS>***</PREMS> 
            <Meters>
               
                <TPLNR>***</TPLNR>
                <VBSARTTEXT>***</VBSARTTEXT>
                <TERMSCHL/>
                <DLNOT>***</DLNOT>
                <STORT>***</STORT>
                <KTEXT>***</KTEXT>
                <EINBDAT>***</EINBDAT>
                <ISPRIM>***</ISPRIM>
                <SERNR>***</SERNR> 
                <MET_SERNR></MET_SERNR>
                <HERST>***</HERST>
                <TYPBZ/>
                <PREISKLA>***</PREISKLA>
                <EQKTX>***</EQKTX>
                <DSTAT>***</DSTAT>
                <MEINS>***</MEINS>
                <STANZVORE>***</STANZVORE>
                <ISTABLART>***</ISTABLART>
                <V_ZWSTAND></V_ZWSTAND> 
                <E_ZWSTANDO>***</E_ZWSTANDO> 
                <E_ZWSTANDU>***</E_ZWSTANDU> 
                <E_VERBERW>***</E_VERBERW> 
                <ADAT>***</ADAT>
                <ATIM>***</ATIM>
                <MTU_TPLNR/>
                <MTUSN>***</MTUSN> >
                <MTU_EQKTX/>
                <MTU_EINBDAT>***11</MTU_EINBDAT>
                <MTU_SERNR></MTU_SERNR>
                <PORT>***</PORT>
            </Meters>
        </MT_ServiceOrderInitiaionandMgmt>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are no big differences between standard rest API requests and XML Soap API requests.

```
cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "Request URL",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
          authorization: "Bearer " + "auth token",
          SOAPAction: "serviceOrder",
        },
        //you have to write your XML body here as a string. I leave a small part 
        //of my API's body to be an example if someone needs it in the future.
        body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><MT_ServiceOrderInitiaionandMgmt xmlns:prx="***" xmlns="***"><VKONTO>5883000</VKONTO><NAME>cypress</NAME><PORTION>MBC87<MTU_EINBDAT>2002-05-11</MTU_EINBDAT><MTU_SERNR></MTU_SERNR><PORT>1</PORT></Meters></MT_ServiceOrderInitiaionandMgmt></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //Do something with the response.
      });
```